# High quality hydrophone for less than $500?

Tags: oceanography

I am doing a hobby project and am in search of a high quality hydrophone for less than $500. I really do not have any idea about such instruments, so I am struggling to make sense of the products on the market -- specifically in terms of how to determine which is better/worse.

And most of the websites, for whatever reason, do not show prices.... e.g., https://oceansonics.com/products/iclisten-sj9/

Importantly, I'd like to be able to hook my hydrophone up to an [NVidia Jetson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BYGB3WV4) for data analysis.

I would really appreciate it if someone could kindly point me to some decent hydrophones that cost $500 or less, and can be interfaced with via something like an [NVidia Jetson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BYGB3WV4).

Comment: What do you want to do with the hydrophone?

Comment: Here is a DIY option: https://hackaday.com/2022/02/19/diy-hydrophone-listens-in-on-the-deep-for-cheap/

Comment: do you need a high quality hydrophone for your project or can you use a simpler underwater microphone?

Comment: @trondhansen It needs to be high quality ;)

Comment: @Jetman I want to listen for various sounds below the water, from low-frequency whale vocalizations to high-frequency industrial noise. I realize I will need to select a frequency 'range' to listen to, but for now I do not care much about that -- I just need a high/scientific quality hydrophone (and whatever other relevant equipment is needed) that I would be able to interface with the Nvidia (or similar, like Pi, arduino, Intel NUC) platform.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I've found a hydrophone that seems to suit your requirements and is within your budget (It's approximately 210 USD)

The H2D hydrophone from Aquarian Hydrophones is recommended for enthusiasts. The H2dm is compatible with Raspberry Pi and Arduino. The hydrophone has low self noise good sensitivity.

Here is a buyers guide: https://acousticnature.com/journal/best-hydrophone-microphones-for-field-recording#google_vignette=